# How to solve for the upper limit of an integral using Newton's method?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I want to write a program that makes use of Newtons Method:

[image: Newtons Method]

To estimate the x of this integral:

[image: Time To Destination integral]

Where X is the total distance.

I have functions to calculate the Time it takes to arrive at a certain distance by using the trapezoid method for numerical integration. Without using trapz.

```
function T = time_to_destination(x, route, n)
h=(x-0)/n;
dx = 0:h:x;
y = (1./(velocity(dx,route)));

Xk = dx(2:end)-dx(1:end-1); 
Yk = y(2:end)+y(1:end-1);

T = 0.5*sum(Xk.*Yk);
end
```

and it fetches its values for velocity, through ppval of a cubic spline interpolation between a set of data points. Where extrapolated values should not be fetcheable.

```
function [v] = velocity(x, route)
load(route);

if all(x >= distance_km(1))==1 & all(x <= distance_km(end))==1
    estimation = spline(distance_km, speed_kmph);
    v = ppval(estimation, x);
else
    error('Bad input, please choose a new value')
end
end
```

Plot of the velocity spline if that's interesting to you evaluated at:

```
dx= 1:0.1:65
```

[image: velocity spline]

Now I want to write a function that can solve for distance travelled after a certain given time, using newton's method without fzero / fsolve . But I have no idea how to solve for the upper bound of a integral.

According to the fundamental theorem of calculus I suppose the derivative of the integral is the function inside the integral, which is what I've tried to recreate as Time_to_destination / (1/velocity)
I added the constant I want to solve for to time to destination so its

(Time_to_destination - (input time)) / (1/velocity)

Not sure if I'm doing that right.

EDIT: Rewrote my code, works better now but my stopcondition for Newton Raphson doesnt seem to converge to zero. I also tried to implement the error from the trapezoid integration ( ET ) but not sure if I should bother implementing that yet. Also find the route file in the bottom.

Stop condition and error calculation of Newton's Method:

[image: https://puu.sh/At3XK/f977969276.png]

Error estimation of trapezoid:

[image: https://puu.sh/At41Q/01c34a8ec1.png]

```
Function x = distance(T, route)
n=180
route='test.mat'
dGuess1 = 50;
dDistance = T;
i = 1;
condition = inf;

while  condition >= 1e-4  && 300 >= i
    i = i + 1 ;
    dGuess2 = dGuess1 - (((time_to_destination(dGuess1, route,n))-dDistance)/(1/(velocity(dGuess1, route))))
    if i >= 2
        ET =(time_to_destination(dGuess1, route, n/2) - time_to_destination(dGuess1, route, n))/3;
        condition = abs(dGuess2 - dGuess1)+ abs(ET);
    end
    dGuess1 = dGuess2;
end
x = dGuess2
```

**Route file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=18GBhlkh5ZND1Ejh0Muyt1aMyK4E2XL3C**

Comment: Good point! Uploaded that now so it should be testable.

Comment: Yes, exactly, you understand me, I want to solve for distance at a given time. Sorry Ill clear that up. Thanks. :)

Comment: It looks like you pretty much solved the problem on your own. The original code didn't make sense to me but what you have looks much better. I started writing my answer before you made the edits. It uses different terminating conditions than yours but you may find it useful so I'll leave it.

Comment: When I run your code now the primary stopping condition `abs(dGuess2 - dGuess1)` goes to zero although `ET` doesn't. It doesn't make sense to expect the trapezoid error to go to zero here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that the Newton-Raphson method determines the roots of the function. I.e. you need to have a function *f(x)* such that *f(x)=0* at the desired solution.

In this case you can define *f* as

*f(x) = Time(x) - t*

where *t* is the desired time. Then by the second fundamental theorem of calculus

*f'(x) = 1/Velocity(x)*

With these functions defined the implementation becomes quite straightforward!

First, we define a simple Newton-Raphson function which takes anonymous functions as arguments (*f* and *f'*) as well as an initial guess *x0*.

```
function x = newton_method(f, df, x0)
    MAX_ITER = 100;
    EPSILON = 1e-5;

    x = x0;
    fx = f(x);
    iter = 0;
    while abs(fx) > EPSILON && iter <= MAX_ITER
        x = x - fx / df(x);
        fx = f(x);
        iter = iter + 1;
    end
end
```

Then we can invoke our function as follows

```
t_given = 0.3;   % e.g. we want to determine distance after 0.3 hours.
n = 180;
route = 'test.mat';
f = @(x) time_to_destination(x, route, n) - t_given; 
df = @(x) 1/velocity(x, route);

distance_guess = 50;
distance = newton_method(f, df, distance_guess);
```

Result

```
>> distance
    distance = 25.5877
```

---

Also, I rewrote your `time_to_destination` and `velocity` functions as follows. This version of `time_to_destination` uses all the available data to make a more accurate estimate of the integral. Using these functions the method seems to converge faster.

```
function t = time_to_destination(x, d, v)
    % x is scalar value of destination distance
    % d and v are arrays containing measured distance and velocity
    % Assumes d is strictly increasing and d(1) <= x <= d(end)
    idx = d < x;
    if ~any(idx)
        t = 0;
        return;
    end
    v1 = interp1(d, v, x);
    t = trapz([d(idx); x], 1./[v(idx); v1]);
end

function v = velocity(x, d, v)
    v = interp1(d, v, x);
end
```

Using these new functions requires that the definitions of the anonymous functions are changed slightly.

```
t_given = 0.3;   % e.g. we want to determine distance after 0.3 hours.
load('test.mat');
f = @(x) time_to_destination(x, distance_km, speed_kmph) - t_given; 
df = @(x) 1/velocity(x, distance_km, speed_kmph);

distance_guess = 50;
distance = newton_method(f, df, distance_guess);
```

Because the integral is estimated more accurately the solution is slightly different

```
>> distance
    distance = 25.7771
```

---

**Edit**

The updated stopping condition can be implemented as a slight modification to the `newton_method` function. We shouldn't expect the trapezoid rule error to go to zero so I omit that.

```
function x = newton_method(f, df, x0)
    MAX_ITER = 100;
    TOL = 1e-5;

    x = x0;
    iter = 0;
    dx = inf;
    while dx > TOL && iter <= MAX_ITER
        x_prev = x;
        x = x - f(x) / df(x);
        dx = abs(x - x_prev);
        iter = iter + 1;
    end
end
```

To check our answer we can plot the time vs. distance and make sure our estimate falls on the curve.

```
...
distance = newton_method(f, df, distance_guess);

load('test.mat');
t = zeros(size(distance_km));
for idx = 1:numel(distance_km)
    t(idx) = time_to_destination(distance_km(idx), distance_km, speed_kmph);
end
plot(t, distance_km); hold on;
plot([t(1) t(end)], [distance distance], 'r');
plot([t_given t_given], [distance_km(1) distance_km(end)], 'r');
xlabel('time');
ylabel('distance');
axis tight;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the main issues with my code was that n was too low, the error of the trapezoidal sum, estimation of my integral, was too high for the newton raphson method to converge to a very small number.

Here was my final code for this problem:

```
function x = distance(T, route)
load(route)
n=10e6;
x = mean(distance_km);
i = 1;
maxiter=100;
tol= 5e-4;
condition=inf
fx = @(x) time_to_destination(x, route,n); 
dfx = @(x) 1./velocity(x, route);

while  condition > tol && i <= maxiter
    i = i + 1 ;
    Guess2 = x - ((fx(x) - T)/(dfx(x)))
    condition = abs(Guess2 - x)
    x = Guess2;

end
end
```